# sqlite consecutive insert statements stop running at around 200

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

So I have an app that I input data in to an sqlite database, it gets that data from a text file dragged in to the documents directory.
The contents look like:

```
file1.pdf, A1, A3, folderName1, 
file2.pdf, A4, A75, folderName2,
```

I have tested it with 10 strings of text. It worked and inserted fine so I decided to create a test that would be a bit more. (357) This would not be the maximum it would be used with but a big enough sample for now.

I ran this and at around 240 ish the insert query changes to Error preparing. And then the following ones start with Error: cannot open database. - the error message I created for sqlite3_open != SQLITE_OK.

```
2016-07-12 09:49:10.289 AppName[897:491157] /       /
2016-07-12 09:49:10.290 AppName[897:491157] INSERT INTO Files (fileName, folder, refNum, endrefNum) SELECT 'file1.pdf', 'Statement', 'S460', 'S460' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT fileName FROM Files WHERE fileName = 'file1.pdf')

2016-07-12 09:49:10.317 AppName[897:491157] /       /
2016-07-12 09:49:10.317 AppName[897:491157] INSERT INTO Files (fileName, folder, refNum, endrefNum) SELECT 'file2.pdf', 'Important', 'S461', 'S461' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT fileName FROM Files WHERE fileName = 'file2.pdf')

2016-07-12 09:49:10.341 AppName[897:491157] /       /
2016-07-12 09:49:10.342 AppName[897:491157] INSERT INTO Files (fileName, folder, refNum, endrefNum) SELECT 'file3.pdf', 'Important', 'S462', 'S463' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT fileName FROM Files WHERE fileName = 'file3.pdf')
2016-07-12 09:49:10.343 AppName[897:491157] Error running insert: INSERT INTO Files (fileName, folder, refNum, endrefNum) SELECT 'file3.pdf', 'Important', 'S462', 'S463' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT fileName FROM Files WHERE fileName = 'file3.pdf')

2016-07-12 09:49:10.343 AppName[897:491157] /       /
2016-07-12 09:49:10.344 AppName[897:491157] Error: cannot open database
2016-07-12 09:49:10.344 AppName[897:491157] INSERT INTO Files (fileName, folder, refNum, endrefNum) SELECT 'file4.pdf', 'Important', 'S464', 'S464' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT fileName FROM Files WHERE fileName = 'file4.pdf')
2016-07-12 09:49:10.344 AppName[897:491157] Error preparing INSERT INTO Files (fileName, folder, refNum, endrefNum) SELECT 'file4.pdf', 'Important', 'S464', 'S464' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT fileName FROM Files WHERE fileName = 'file4.pdf')
```

Above is a snippet of my output showing my INSERT statement and the error messages that appear. As you can see the first two went in as normal. Then the 3rd file had an issue with running the INSERT statement. Then from then on the rest of the files cant open the database which I assume is why it can't prepare the statement.

**What I have tried**

I assumed that the reason it was doing it was because a certain line
    was throwing it off. - I cut the lower half of the text file and pasted it to the top. The first lot went in fine so this was not the reason.

I have noticed that there is a command called transaction on sqlite for android that is used for multiple insert queries. Do I need to do something similar to that for iOS?

```
-(void) addFileName:(NSString *)fileName
                        fileType:(NSString *)fileType
                        refNumber:(NSString *)bates
                           fileLocation:(NSString *)location
                 endrefNumber:(NSString *)endBates
{
    long long fileID;
    NSLog(@"/       /");
    [self openDB];

    // Names Table
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Files (fileName, folder, refNum, endrefNum) SELECT '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT fileName FROM Files WHERE fileName = '%@')", fileName, fileType, bates, endBates, fileName];
    NSLog(@"%@",insertSQL);
    const char* query1 = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt * query1_stmt = NULL;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query1, -1, &query1_stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Error preparing %@", insertSQL);
        [self closeDB];
        return;
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(query1_stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"Error running insert: %s", query1);
        [self closeDB];
        return;
    }
    // row id
    fileID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    // phones table
    insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Location (FileID, Location) VALUES (%lld, '%@')", fileID, location];
    const char* query2 = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt * query2_stmt = NULL;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query2, -1, &query2_stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Error preparing %@", insertSQL);
        [self closeDB];
        return;
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(query2_stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"Error running insert: %s", query2);
        [self closeDB];
        return;
    }

    [self closeDB];
}
```

Open Database

```
-(void) openDB
{
    if ( (sqlite3_open([[self dbDocPath] UTF8String], &database)) != SQLITE_OK )
        NSLog(@"Error: cannot open database");
}
```

Close Database

```
-(void) closeDB
{
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

**UPDATE**

So I have made it so that the database opens once, inserts all of the data, then closes once it has done. This seems that the opening and closing of the database is what caused the issues. Still seems a bit strange to me, if anyone could explain why that would be helpful.

Comment: A single transaction for all inserts would be needed for peformance. But your problem is that it does not work at all, because of a bug in your code (which you have not shown).

Comment: Added code, what I am trying to do now is open the connection, read and insert and then close the connection rather than opening and closing for each insert statement.

Comment: Why do you open/close the database for every query?  Open it and keep it open and only close it when the app goes into the background.  Only open it if it's closed and only close it if it's open (this requires guard code).  Also opening the database can fail, so you need a return value and you need to check it.

Comment: You forgot [sqlite3_finalize()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html).

Comment: @Droppy Yeah, that was it. Just updated the post, so I assume opening and closing were corrupting the file? This has obviously made the process faster as well.

Comment: @kni9ht Yeah drop your call to `[self closeDB]` and put those into the app delegate methods that relate to the app going into the background etc.  Just always put a check for `[self openDB]` at the start of all database-related methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I have made it so that the database opens once, inserts all of the
>   data, then closes once it has done. This seems that the opening and
>   closing of the database is what caused the issues. Still seems a bit
>   strange to me, if anyone could explain why that would be helpful.

The issues, as I see them, are:

1. You don't check if the database is already open or already closed.
2. You don't check if opening the database failed.

A small amount of guard code should solve that:

```
-(BOOL) openDB
{
    BOOL opened = YES;
    if (database == NULL) {
        if ( (sqlite3_open([[self dbDocPath] UTF8String], &database)) != SQLITE_OK ) {
            // Use sqlite3_errmsg() to tell us why it didn't open!
            NSLog(@"Error: cannot open database");
            opened = NO;
        }
    }
    return opened;
}

-(void) closeDB
{
    if (database != NULL) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        database = NULL;
    }
}
```

(I hope `database` is an instance variable and not a global?).

Also you need to check if it opened OK:

```
if (![self openDB])
    return;
```

and also from @CL:

> You forgot `sqlite3_finalize()`.